# ruby regex match any character besides a specific one

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking for a way to match any character besides, for example, a "#."

It would look something like...

```
gsub(/^foo.*foo$/)
```

But I'd want it to match

```
"foofdfdfdfoo"
```

But not

```
"fooddgdgd#fdfoo"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
^[^#]+$
```

http://rubular.com/r/glijo99dU9

`gsub` is for substitution.  If you just want to match, the `.match` method

Comment: Ya I'm aware of that.  I just thought I'd give it some context.

Comment: Using `=~` is an anachronism from Perl. It's preferable to use `match` instead.

Comment: You usually want `\a` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$`.

Comment: `gsub` is for *global* substitution. `sub` is for a single substitution.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Explosion Pills answer, a caret (^) will negate the match in a regex. This means that it will not match if the characters following it are found in the expression. You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Comment: This behavior of `^` only applies to character classes

Comment: Yes, in the case at the beginning of the regular expression `^` matches beginning of the line.